# How to find posts tagged with any of the predefined tags in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have posts table with the following structure:

```
| id  | score | title  | tags                   | 
-------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   42  | Travel | <uk><travel><passport> |
```

For each blog post I want to find relevant posts, tagged with any of the tags corresponding to the current page, in my case: `<uk>`, `<travel>` or `<passport>`. Then, order results by score, limit it to 5 items and display it to the user.

This is the code I came up with so far, but it seems only getting the result for the first tag in the query – `<uk>`.

```
with tags_string (tag) as (
    select unnest(string_to_array('<uk><travel><passport>', '>'))
)
select *
from
    (
     select distinct *
     from posts
     cross join tags_string
     cross join lateral
       (select
          (tags ~ tag)::int as match_found
       ) m
     where m.match_found > 0
    ) t
order by t.score desc
limit 5;
```

**EDIT**
After @Mike Organek's comment I changed the query this, and it's working as I initially expected.

```
with tags_string (tag) as (
    select unnest(string_to_array('<uk><travel><passport>', '>'))
)
select *
from
    (
     select distinct *
     from posts
     cross join tags_string
     cross join lateral
       (select
          position(tag in tags) > 0 as match_found
       ) m
     where m.match_found and tag <> ''
    ) t
order by t.score desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: Splitting on either angle bracket will create an empty string as an element of the resulting array.  Doing `~` with an empty string on the right-hand side and a non-null `text` on the left-hand side  always returns `true`.  I do not see how your query could possibly work as written.

Comment: @MikeOrganekThanks, I rewrote the query to check that string is non-empty and use `position()` instead of `~`

Comment: its working now as expected

Comment: It would be a lot easier if the tags were stored as a proper array or maybe a jsonb column. This format is a nightmare to deal with

Comment: You do not aggregate in your innermost subquery.  Are you intending to get `sum((tags ~ tag)::int)` as a count of matches found?  (I know you switched to using `position()`, but the question should be the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the tags into an array then use array operators to find the relevant posts:

```
select id, title, score, tags
from posts
where string_to_array(trim(both '<>' from replace(tags, '><', ',')), ',') @> array['uk', 'travel', 'passport']
order by score
limit 5
```

In the long run, storing the tags as an array or a jsonb array is probably a lot more efficient.

If you do that a lot, things might get a bit easier if you create a function for this:

```
create function tags_array(p_input text)
returns text[]
as
$$
  select string_to_array(trim(both '<>' from replace(p_input, '><', ',')), ',');
$$
language sql 
immutable;
```

Then the query is a bit easier to read:

```
select id, title, score, tags
from posts
where tags_array(tags) @> array['uk', 'travel', 'passport']
order by score
limit 5
```

You can even create an index for that if you want:

```
create index on posts using gin ( (tags_array(tags)) );
```